# Error: Could not find or load main class pj2 on bash

Tags: java, parallel-processing, graph-coloring

I know this question has been asked many times however I have surfed through a lot of solutions and not been able to find any concrete answer. I am trying to use the Parallel 2 Library by Prof. Alan Kimisky, termed pj2.

This library is used for [this](https://github.com/shreyasj2006/Parallel-Programming-Solution-to-the-Graph-Coloring-Problem) graph coloring problem. 
My file directory looks something like this

[image]

I had to extract pj2.jar and copy-paste the edu file to project folder so that all the .java files could compile

First compiled all my files by the command

```
javac *.java
```

After that we used the command as mentioned in the GitHub Project

```
java pj2 cores=1 GraphColSeq sampleInput
```

An error is displayed after this

```
Error: Could not find or load main class pj2
```

Hence I came across a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263309/unable-to-use-parallel-java-2-library-by-prof-alan-kaminsky-could-not-find-or) online. However when setting the path of pj2 with command

```
export CLASSPATH=.:/C/TabuParallelProgrammingAlgorithm/pj2.jar
```

the error yet is displayed. I tried most of the solutions online however the same error persists.

**Computer Specification**

Windows 10, i7, jdk 1.7

**Update**

As mentioned by both the proposed solutions I downloaded the executable file of pj2 and now my directory looks like this

[image]

There is no `lib` directory and `pj2.class` is present in `pj2/` itself.

I typed the following commands -

```
javac -cp pj2/ *.java
```

And it compiled without any issues

However when I typed

```
java -cp .:pj2/ pj2 cores=4 GrpahColSeq sampleInput.txt
```

The error comes again

```
Error: Could not find or load main class pj2
```

I believe it has something to do with the way I write `pj2` in the command shell. Maybe the exact file path must be required. Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: check if the `pj2.jar` file is not corrupted, open it with winzip or 7-zip and look for `pj2.class` in the main folder (or use `jar -tvf pj2.jar`)

Comment: Yes pj2.class file is present

Comment: `java -cp .:pj2.jar pj2 cores=4 GrpahColSeq sampleInput.txt` **or** eventually  `java -cp .:pj2 pj2 cores=4 GrpahColSeq sampleInput.txt` (bash on windows is a bit weird, sometimes,...)

Comment: editing answer since question changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have downloaded the **source** distribution file:

> Version 20-Jun-2018 (6,399,014 bytes): **pj2src_20180620.jar**

Get the **executable** one:

> Version 20-Jun-2018 (1,133,935 bytes): **pj2_20180620.jar**

Note the file sizes!

<sub>the `pj2_20180620.jar` file should be renamed to `pj2.jar`</sub>

**Update** <sub>since question also updated/changed.</sub>

The problem **now** is that windows uses ':' as drive separator, so java must use ';' to separate the classpath components (despite running on bash). And bash uses ';' to separate commands, so we need to escape it.

Try:

```
java -cp '.;pj2' pj2 cores=4 GrpahColSeq sampleInput.txt
```

or, (not tested) without the need to *unjar* or to compile `pj2`

```
java -cp '.;pj2.jar' pj2 ores=4 GrpahColSeq sampleInput.txt
```

Same for using `CLASSPATH`

```
export CLASSPATH='.;pj2.jar'
java pj2 cores=4 GrpahColSeq sampleInput.txt
```

<sup>this does not *invalidate* the prior answer!</sup>

Comment: I got the executable one and yet the issue persists

Comment: Thank you so much, the update worked like a charm for me :). And yes, I tested all your commands and every one of them is running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to compile `pj2` (if there is no `pj2.class` in `pj2/lib` directory):

```
javac *.java -cp pj2/lib/
```

now you must find this file: `pj2/lib/pj2.class`

then you need to compile your java files:

```
javac -cp pj2/lib/ *.java
```

now you can run what you want:

```
java -cp .:pj2/lib/ pj2 cores=4 GraphColSeq sampleInput.txt 
Vertex:0,color:0
Vertex:1,color:1
Vertex:2,color:0
Vertex:3,color:0
Vertex:4,color:2
Total number of colors required:3
0 msec
```